# Filter RSS content based on Group in MailChimp

Tags: rss, mailchimp, newsletter

I am trying to create a newsletter with [MailChimp](http://www.mailchimp.com) that will display different RSS feeds based on the users interests. 
When they sign up for the newsletter they can pick multiple interests from a list, so for instance:

- Fitness
- Meditation
- Health

What I want to do in MailChimp is use the following for each interest:

```
*|INTERESTED:Interests:Fitness|*
*|FEEDBLOCK:fitness-feed|*
*|FEEDITEMS: [$count=3]|*
*|FEEDITEM:TITLE|*

*|FEEDITEM:CONTENT|*

*|END:FEEDITEMS|*
*|END:FEEDBLOCK|*
*|END:INTERESTED|*
```

But, when I send the newsletter out to my test audience, the e-mails come up empty, even though the people are part of the correct groups. If I send them without the RSS feeds, and just with plain text instead, the text will display correctly.

Does MailChimp not let you send these types of RSS e-mails, where you display multiple feeds based on interests? And, if not, is there any way around it? Or am I just doing something wrong with my code?